# After updating PhpStorm, JS autocomplete stopped working in php files

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

So after updating PhpStorm from 2017.1 to 2017.2, JavaScript autocomplete stopped working in JavaScript, that is embedded inside of PHP file. Nothing works, not core JS method autocomplete, and not even the most basic declared variable autocomplete.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug/regression in PhpStorm 2017.2 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36767) and it's fixed for **2017.2.1**.

---

If you wish -- **you may install 2017.2.1 EAP build now** and not wait until 2017.2.1 final will be officially released: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/07/phpstorm-2017-2-1-eap-172-3544/

**UPDATE:** 2017.2.1 has been released -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/08/phpstorm-2017-2-1-is-here/