# JavaScript code is not suggested in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have a problem, my PhpStorm is not suggest JavaScript code

[image]

This is my trouble: I try to write `var` and got "no suggestion" error in bottom: "Expression statement is not assignment or call"

Following some solution in Internet, but not working
I've uninstalled PhpStorm and reinstall ultimate version but nothing different.

Comment: I can see absolutely nothing in your image. Can you enlarge it or something?

Comment: What if you write to a .js file, not within a <script> tag?

Comment: sorry about my fault, i try to write "var" and some simple javascript func (alert, confirm....) but got "no suggestion". i'm very confused

Comment: Add type="text/javascript" to script tag and check settings of PhpStorm if it has javascript libraries enabled

Comment: bro, no error when i write in js file, it have suggestion, but in php file i got no suggestion, in my other laptop, no error occured

Comment: Make javascript autocomplete globally available in settings and add type tag to <script>

Comment: Within settings you have search option

Comment: what 's this setting option name? bro

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9BRt.png

Comment: My setting option:
https://scontent.fhan4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/20542891_1126246294142475_857761507_o.png?oh=b6f58a2d862168d8ec632032eac99742&oe=598302C9

Comment: not working bro :(
https://scontent.fhan4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/20590644_1126246550809116_1331382415_o.png?oh=501a7f16cca61465d16ef5af74c51ffd&oe=5982B8F6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45433123/783119 ?

Answer (score 1):

[WI-36767](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36767) is fixed, fix will be included in next minor update of PhpStorm.

You can try the [EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) to see if it works for you